# How to transfer [String] information through a socket

Tags: java, sockets, exception, serversocket, printwriter

I'm trying to make a client chat application using Java
I want to transfer messages but Its seems like its not working.
`Typing` is a `JTextField`

`Button` is a `button` (No way :O)

and `ChatView` is the `JTextArea`for sending messages between the clients
Leave the `length()` its there so the `button` doesn't accept spam.

Heres code

```
 public  void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
     int x = Typing.getText().length();
      if (x > 0)  {
     System.out.println(Typing.getText().length());
     ChatView.insert("\n"+Typing.getText(),0);
     Typing.setText("");}
       try {
    ServerSocket MainServer = new ServerSocket(344);
Socket Connect = MainServer.accept();  
OutputStream outstream =  Connect.getOutputStream(); 
 PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(Connect.getOutputStream());
 out.print("Works");   
} catch (Exception ee) {
    System.err.print("/n"+"error");
}
```

Comment: Show your client side code as well... the reading part from socket. May be the problem is in client code

Comment: Wait what ? We have to read from a socket ?

Comment: The code you showed is just the server side code .. show the client side code which is accepting `"Works"`

Comment: Ok Well i'm new to sockets like three days. What my idea was to send message to server socket then add a listener to update the jtextarea.  So i don't have a client side

Comment: Hahaha.. Dude ..  First try a simple Socket program .. then jump to big things.. simply hit google Socket programming

Comment: AJ i fixed it apparently i mistakenly pasted two tries on my notepad

Answer (score 0):

The problem is , stream should be flushed if some body is trying to read that stream

After `out.print("Works");` either flush the the stream or close the srtream

`out.flush();` or `out.close();`